# Getting custom web.config sections and their contents in Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7.5, web.config

I have a web application installed in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot_Site1\AppName` which has a custom section group and section as follows:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="Libraries">
    <section name="Custom.Section.Name" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="Custom.Section.Name2" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

I've written the following snippet of Powershell:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-WebConfiguration //Libraries IIS:\Sites\Site1\AppName
```

Which correctly returns:

> Name         Sections                           Groups
>
> ====          ========                        ===========
>
> Libraries    Custom.Section.Name
>
> Custom.Section.Name2

What I can't fathom is how to, either via `Get-WebConfiguration` or `Get-WebConfigurationProperty` obtain access to the `<add key="x" value="y" />` elements that are direct children of CustomSectionName in the actual "body" of the configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just so happens that I recently put this function into a PowerShell web framework I write.

Here's the trio of lines you'll need:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$webConfigStore = [Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager]::OpenWebConfiguration($path)              
$customSetting = $webConfigStore.AppSettings.Settings["$Setting"];
```

The third will vary somewhat depending on what you're trying to get.

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

If the web application is of the SharePoint 2007 variety, you can pick off a single appSetting from its web.config via:

```
param ( [string] $url='http://contso.com')

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Web') | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint') | Out-Null

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $site = New-Object -TypeName  'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite' -ArgumentList $url

[System.Configuration.Configuration] $config = [System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager]::OpenWebConfiguration('/', $site.WebApplication.Name)

<p># pull the one appSetting string we're interested in 

[string] $appSettingKey = 'avalidkey'

[string] $appSettingValue = $config.AppSettings.Settings[$appSettingKey].Value

Write-Host ("<appSetting> Key={0}, Value={1}" -f $appSettingKey, $appSettingValue)

$config = $null

$site.Dispose()

$site = $null
```